# Azure Application gateway with lets encrypt

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault, lets-encrypt, azure-application-gateway

I have an AKS cluster running running Internal nginx ingress +  cert-manager which generates lets encrypt for ssl terminations.

I would like to include application gateway as an entry point, where I expect that SSL internet traffic hits Applicatiom Gateway and traffic is forwarded to the nginx ingress, then to my application. I do not mind if SSL offloading is done at Appgw level or on the AKS cluster itself.

One of my biggest headaches is that Application gateway requires a certificate when an https listener is created. Since the certifiate is generated automatically on the AKS cluster I do not see the benefit of supplying an SSL certificate to the Application Gateway neither do I want to go through the extra work of generating a certificate and storing it keyvault etc etc.

What is the neatest way to tackle this problem? Potential solutions I have considered are

- Configure Application Gateway to passthrough SSL to the AKS cluster
- Somehow configure cert-manager to store the certificate in keyvault

The only options I see are (but I like neither are)

- Purchase a certificate and store it in keyvault (however I prefer using Lets Encrypt)
- Generate the SSL certificate on a cluster and then write a script which scrapes the certificate and stores it in Azure Key Vault

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Since the above hasn't solution hasn't really helped me, I had decided to write an aks cron job which syncs certificates to azure keyvault.

If anyone is interested, I would be able to open source it.

Comment: I have exactly the same situation with a single AGW and AKS clusters over multiple subscriptions. If you could share or contact I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: [This](https://github.com/michelefa1988/cert_sync) is what I made and still use. It works like a charm. The only thing is I did not have time to do a helm chart and proper documentation for it yet. Nevertheless I did try to write some points

Answer (score 1):

As per [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-letsencrypt-certificate-application-gateway) here you can use cert-manager an AKS add-on that automates the creation and management of certificates.
You can also go through [this tutoria](https://intelequia.com/blog/post/1012/automating-azure-application-gateway-ssl-certificate-renewals-with-let-s-encrypt-and-azure-automation)l which uses Azure automation runbook to automate certificate rotation for ApGw.